# Coloring m things with k colors, using each color at least once.

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of ways of coloring $m$ things with $k$ colors, using each color at least once? Yes, inclusion-exclusion gives that the answer is $k^m - \binom{k}{1} (k-1)^m + \binom{k}{2} (k-2)^m - \binom{k}{3} (k-3)^m + ...$, but I'd like an expression from which one can get an asymptotic easily (for $k$ large and $m \sim c k$, where $c$ is a constant greater than $1$).

Answer (score 1):

That’s $k!{m\brace k}$, where $m\brace k$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). The linked article has some information on [asymptotic approximations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Asymptotic_approximation). There may be more useful information in the references in the [OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A008277).