# Is this Inclusion-Exclusion: $m$ balls colored $n$ colors such that each color is represented?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, stirling-numbers

Suppose you have $m$ balls each of which can be colored by $n<m$ different colors, and your paint cans are unlimited.  I want to count the number of ways that you can color balls such that each color is represented at least once.  I reasoned that this can be counted by something that seems ... "philosophically" similar to inclusion-exclusion.  But when I try to actually align this counting method with the actual inclusion-exclusion method, I can't seem to perfectly describe how this counting method is an application of inclusion-exclusion.

**Here's my solution**:  First over-estimate the number of colorings by all possible assignments of colors to balls:  $n^m$.

Next we subtract out those colorings in which some color is absent.  There are $\binom n 1$ choices of one color, and for each, we can color each ball by $(n-1)^m$ colors.  So our new estimate is

$$ n^m - \binom n 1 (n-1)^m $$

However, there are some colorings that are double-counted by this subtraction.  In particular the colorings which are lacking two colors are double-counted (and the colorings missing three colors are triple-counted, and so on).  So to correct for this we add back in $\binom n 2 (n-2)^m$.

$$ n^m - \binom n 1 (n-1)^m + \binom n 2 (n-2)^m $$

We continue the process until, with just one color left, double-countings no longer occur.  So the number is

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^i \binom{n}{n-i}(n-i)^m $$

**Edit**: I tried searching for this in the recommendations that StackExchange gives, and didn't see anything that looked very relevant.  But now on the sidebar I see this link:  [Coloring m things with k colors, using each color at least once.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107163/coloring-m-things-with-k-colors-using-each-color-at-least-once?rq=1)

So this is a known problem, but is there a way to view it as an instance of inclusion-exclusion, or is the similarity just superficial?

Comment: This is a classical application of PIE.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave it as

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n}i(n-i)^m$$

or even

$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}i(n-i)^m\,,$$

but what you’ve done is fine and is exactly an inclusion-exclusion argument. The Stirling numbers mentioned in the answer to the earlier question that you found [can be calculated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Explicit_formula) by essentially the same inclusion-exclusion argument.

Comment: But how is it inclusion-exclusion?  If you set $A_i$ to be the set of colorings with color $i$, represented, then you want $|A_1\cap \dots\cap A_n|$, then this kinda sorta aligns with computing $|A_1\cap A_2|$ and similar quantities, but it doesn't seem to be exactly the same.

Comment: @Addem: I’ll write it out if necessary, but first take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement) and try to match it up with what you did. The set $A_i$ is the set of colorings that don’t use color $i$, and the calculation at the link then gives you the number of colorings that exclude at least one color. Subtract that from $n^m$, and you have your result.